# Deserialize a JSON object into its original class

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am trying to serialize/deserialize an object. I am thinking that the best way would be to save the path to the file that called as part of the json, but I am unsure of how to get said path.

Can getting this path to the file (`A.ts`/`B.ts`) be done when called within the parent (`Base.ts`)?

Is there maybe a better approach to doing this? I am trying to take a class created in the main node process, and and pass it to a worker process, the only why to do this that I can see is to serialize/deserialize the class somehow.

```
// src/Base.ts
export abstract class Base {

  public serialize() {
    return JSON.stringify({path: '', obj: this})
  }

  public static deserialize(json: string) {
    let { path, obj } = JSON.parse(json) as { path: string, obj: { [key: string]: any } }

    let newable = require(path)
    let o = new newable
    return Object.assign(o, obj)
  }

}

// src/filter/A.ts
export class A extends Base {
  public cat: string = 'meow'
  public sayHi() { return this.cat }
}

// src/filter/B.ts
export class B extends Base {
  public dog: string = 'woof'
  public sayHi() { return this.dog }
}

// test.ts
let serializedA = new A().serialize()
let serializedB = new B().serialize()
// Create child...
let worker = cp.fork(path.join(__dirname, './worker'), [], { silent: true })
worker.send({ serializedA, serializedB })

// worker.ts
process.on('message', msg => {
  let classA = Base.deserialize(msg.serializedA)
  let classB = Base.deserialize(msg.serializedB)
})
```